# Can't access to ViewBag (have a list of JSON objects ) from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In My ASPMVC Code I filled the ViewBag.Contacts variable by use the below code

```
        var contactsGroups = EntityContext.DBContext.TS_GetConfirmedContacts(typeId,AccountId).GroupBy(c=>c.GroupName);
       // JSONGroup Custom object  
       List<JSONGroup> jsonContactsGroups = new List<JSONGroup>();
        foreach (var group in contactsGroups)
        {
            jsonContactsGroups.Add(new JSONGroup
            {
                GroupName = group.Key,
                Objects = new List<object>(group.ToList())
            });
        }


        var result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = jsonContactsGroups,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };

        ViewBag.Contacts =  result;
```

When I am tried to access the ViewBag.Contacts variable from javascript by this Code

```
var contactData = '@ViewBag.Contacts';
```

After debugging the value returned as string  [from console]

> var contactData = 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use JsonResult to return a Json formated string. JsonResult class is inherited from ActionResult class, so the returned value is an object containing Json formated 'Data' property and some other properties for response. so and using @ symbol to output the result , will return the name of class as string.
if you want to serialize an object to a Json object , use [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serializer or use the .NET build in JavaScriptSerializer class.

**Newtonsoft :**

```
String serializedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonContactsGroups);
```

**JavaScriptSerializer :**

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer() ;
String serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(result);
```

Then return the Json serialized string to the view :

```
ViewBag.Contacts =  serializedResult;
```

***But*** if you want to return a Json model or result to the view , i suggest you to write your action method as JsonResult method.

Comment: Using NewtonSoft worked for me, though I had to prepend `JsonConvert` with `Newtonsoft.Json` as in `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Html.Raw** and **Json.Encode** like

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Contacts));

// fetch data

$.each(model.Data, function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("GroupName"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)(it may already be referenced since MVC uses it as default serializer)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

ViewBag.Contacts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonContactsGroups, Formatting.Indented);
```